# How to query Direct returning visitor in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out how many users returned as Direct users after visiting the website as Organic using BigQuery

This is what I did so far. In order to get the number of users who came back as Direct after visiting as Organic, I used 
organic_user.visitNumber < direct_user.visitNumber
in WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
  organic_user.date,
  COUNT (DISTINCT direct_user.fullVisitorId) AS return_direct_user
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      fullVisitorId,
      visitNumber
    FROM
      `ga_sessions_*`,
      UNNEST(hits) as hits
    WHERE
      DATE BETWEEN '20190814'
      AND '20190911'
      AND channelGrouping = 'Organic Search'
  ) AS organic_user
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      date,
      fullVisitorId,
      visitNumber
    FROM
      `ga_sessions_*`,
      UNNEST(hits) as hits
    WHERE
      DATE BETWEEN '20190814'
      AND '20190911'
      AND channelGrouping = 'Direct'
  ) AS direct_user ON organic_user.fullVisitorId = direct_user.fullVisitorId
WHERE
  organic_user.visitNumber < direct_user.visitNumber
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date ASC
```

Could anyone verify this query is correct?
If not, could you provide a solution for this?

Comment: This query seems correct to me, are you experiencing any unexpected results?

Comment: I found that the COUNT (DISTINCT fullvisitorID) will return different results depending on the alias I use ("organic_user" and "direct_user" in this example), when I add channelgrouping to SELECT clause. So wondering which alias should I use in SELECT clause.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I tried to add the `channelGrouping` to the SELECT clauses, but still got the same results. For this query structure it should not really matter which one you choose. The only thing I would consider changing would be to add a WHERE clause to the ‘Organic Search’ to get only the ones that are `visitNumber = 1`. Especially if you want to check Direct visits that came after those that were originally from Organic Search.

Comment: @pessolato thank you for your suggestion. For example, if I used direct_user.channelGrouping in SELECT clause and not use channelGrouping = 'Direct' in direct_user, I got a different number for each channel in the results.
Also, another thing is, the number of COUNT (DISTINCT fullvisitorID) in result turned out to be always higher than total number of Returning visitor in GA, which is weird because my query has multiple conditions. 
Because of these reasons, I'm not sure if this query is correct.

Comment: I am wondering should I be adding 'visitId' into INNER JOIN condition?

Comment: I don’t see how adding the `visitId` to the JOIN condition would help you, maybe doing something with the dates would be better. The thing is, counting by date can be a bit tricky in this case. Do you want to know all the users that visited “Directly” after having visited “Organically“ on the same day, or on any previous day? I’ve been playing around with the [google_analytics_sample](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738?hl=en) which comes from the Google Merchandise Store, if you give me more info about your use case maybe I can come with something up.

Comment: Thank you @pessolato. Yes, I want to know the number of all users that visited “Directly” after having visited “Organically“ on the same day and the date does not matter to me. So for example, the user who visited organically 11 days ago and came back to the website Directly 2 days ago should be still counted to the query results.

Answer (score 0):

With all the clarifications you provided in the comments, I was able to come up with some adaptations of your original query:

```
SELECT
  direct_user.date,
  COUNT (DISTINCT direct_user.fullVisitorId) AS return_direct_user
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorId,
    visitNumber
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data`.google_analytics_sample.`ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    DATE BETWEEN '20161214'
    AND '20180911'
    AND channelGrouping = 'Organic Search' ) AS organic_user
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorId,
    visitNumber
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data`.google_analytics_sample.`ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    DATE BETWEEN '20161214'
    AND '20180911'
    AND channelGrouping = 'Direct' ) AS direct_user
ON
  organic_user.fullVisitorId = direct_user.fullVisitorId
AND organic_user.visitNumber < direct_user.visitNumber
GROUP BY
  direct_user.date
ORDER BY
  direct_user.date ASC
```

Here are some considerations about the changes I made:

1. I noticed it was important to specify the subquery group `date` we
   are using for the group by. Since we are counting ‘Direct’ visits
   per day, it makes sense we count when they happen.
2. I moved the `organic_user.visitNumber < direct_user.visitNumber`
   condition to the JOIN clause, I know for INNER JOINs it does not
   make any technical difference, but for semantic reasons I thought it
   belong there.

I hope this information results to be helpful to you.